# Override a method in another class

Tags: java

I want the class MyContent.class wil be used in others projects, like a library, but it's posible to pass the code will be used inside the onChange when I create it?

**MyContent.class**

```
public class MyContent extends ContentObserver {

  @Override
  public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
  }
}
```

**Main.class**:

```
  public class Main extends AsyncTask {
      MyContent myContent= new MyContent(new Handler());

      @Override
      public void myContent.onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        //posibility to use the uri parameter
        Log.d("d", "onChange fired");
      }
  }
```

Output:
OnChange fired*

Comment: Be more clear, what exactly are you asking

Comment: I update my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) which inherits from `MyContent` and overrides the method:

```
public class Main extends AsyncTask {
    MyContent myContent = new MyContent(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
            //posibility to use the uri parameter
            Log.d("d", "onChange fired");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: It's posible to make onChange outside " { } "? Like a normal method

Comment: @richard1994x No. The only way to override a method at the time of object creation is to use an anonymous class, which requires this syntax.

Comment: And, something like this:

       @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
          myMethod();
        }

        myMethod() {
          //export this method
        }

Comment: @richard1994x I don't know what you mean by "export this method", but yes, you can call methods in `Main` from inside the anonymous class, since inner classes have access to the outer class.

Comment: I getting the error "method does not override method from its superclass"

Comment: @richard1994x `MyContent` must have an `onChange` method, and it must have the same parameters list as the one in your anonymous class.